# Delete directory with files in it?

Tags: php, rmdir

I wonder, what's the easiest way to delete a directory with all its files in it?

I'm using `rmdir(PATH . '/' . $value);` to delete a folder, however, if there are files inside of it, I simply can't delete it.

Comment: Just want to note. I created multiple files and if during the process get some error, then need to delete the previously created files. When created files, forgot to use `fclose($create_file);` and when delete, got `Warning: unlink(created_file.xml): Permission denied in...`. So to avoid such errors must close created files.

Answer (score 447, accepted):

There are at least two options available nowadays.

1. Before deleting the folder, delete all its files and folders (and this means recursion!). Here is an example:

   ```
   function deleteDir(string $dirPath): void {
       if (! is_dir($dirPath)) {
           throw new InvalidArgumentException("$dirPath must be a directory");
       }
       if (substr($dirPath, strlen($dirPath) - 1, 1) != '/') {
           $dirPath .= '/';
       }
       $files = glob($dirPath . '*', GLOB_MARK);
       foreach ($files as $file) {
           if (is_dir($file)) {
               deleteDir($file);
           } else {
               unlink($file);
           }
       }
       rmdir($dirPath);
   }
   ```
2. And if you are using 5.2+ you can use a RecursiveIterator to do it without implementing the recursion yourself:

   ```
   function removeDir(string $dir): void {
       $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
       $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it,
                    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
       foreach($files as $file) {
           if ($file->isDir()){
               rmdir($file->getPathname());
           } else {
               unlink($file->getPathname());
           }
       }
       rmdir($dir);
   }
   ```

Comment: little add-on :-) glob() does not support files like .htaccess. I used the function to clear directories made by KCFinder (CKEditor plugin) which generates both .htaccess and .thumbs (file + folder).

Instead I used the `scandir` function to get the folder list. Just make sure you filter the '.' and '..' files from the result list.

Comment: DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is not necessary when you're building paths to send _to_ the os. Windows will accept forward slashes too. Its mainly useful for `explode()`ing a path taken _from_ the OS. http://alanhogan.com/tips/php/directory-separator-not-necessary

Comment: The second example still does not always delete all sub-folders.  For example I tested on a  folder that had several subfolders and files which all also had subfolders and files.  After the first run it deleted everything except the top level folder and left and subfolders in it, the subfolders are now empty though.  SO I had to refresh the page a few times to get it to delete all the fsubfolders

Comment: For the second solution, it doesn't work if you have a lot of sub directories that have their own directories including files.

Comment: Please add is_array check to $files variable before using it in a foreach.

Comment: change your glob impl to "$files = glob($dirPath . '{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE);" and check for dots in last-pos of file-name (and continue those) -> and this method can handle hidden files nicely... thx for the base-impl :)

Comment: In addition to @Alix Axel

Using here the [SplFileInfo::getRealPath()] (http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getrealpath.php) is not a good idea. This method expands all symbolic links, that means, will be deleted a real file from somewhere instead a symlink from the target directory.
You should use SplFileInfo::getPathname() instead.

Comment: `glob($dirPath . '{,.}[!.,!..]*',GLOB_BRACE)` will skips `./` and `../` but keeps dot-files.

Comment: I agree with @Vijit, use getPathname() instead of getRealPath(). It does the same thing without deleting more than what you are expecting to if symlinks are found.

Comment: First solution doesn't seem to delete hidden files (namely `.DS_Store` files in macOS), so deleting the directory fails at the end.

Comment: If you can't execute `rmdir()` at the end of the second implementation, you could try adding `$ri->endIteration();` right before it.

Comment: RecursiveDirectoryIterator doesn't require PHP 5.3. But SKIP_DOTS does

Answer (score 266):

I generally use this to delete all files in a folder:

```
array_map('unlink', glob("$dirname/*.*"));
```

And then you can do

```
rmdir($dirname);
```

Comment: This doesn't delete folders recursively; it only works if the folder has only regular files in it, all of which have file extensions.

Comment: If no recursion is needed this is the best and simpliest answer so far. Thanks!

Comment: In order to remove *all* files from a folder, not only the ones with extensions, use glob in the following way:
`array_map('unlink', glob("$dirname/*"));`
This still doesn't allow you to delete directories nested in the folder.

Comment: Note that this will remove dot (hidden) files as well.

Comment: To delete folders recursively, just do `array_map("unlink", glob("$dirname/*")); array_map("rmdir", glob("$dirname/*")); rmdir($dirname);`.

Answer (score 106):

> what's the easiest way to delete a directory with all its files in it?

```
system("rm -rf ".escapeshellarg($dir));
```

Comment: I hope you're not serious. What happens if $dir is /

Comment: @The exactly the same as with any of the codes above. Isn't it?

Comment: Note that, depending how `$dir` is generated/provided, you may need to do some additional pre-processing to be safe and to avoid bugs.  For example, if `$dir` might have an unescaped space or semi-colon in it, then there could be undesirable side effects.  This is not the case with the answers that use things like `rmdir()` because it will handle the special characters for you.

Comment: Windows version: `system('rmdir '.escapeshellarg($path).' /s /q');`

Comment: At the very least you should explain some caveats for such a dangerous answer.  `$dir` needs to be sanitized, it's unix-specific, it relies on something many sysadmins disallow (shelling out a command), etc.  This is the "easiest" solution only when very specific conditions are met.

Comment: @ThePixelDeveloper you shouldn't worry about deleting /, this would only work if you'd lounch the script in command line as root, because in web everything happens as apache user

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/disable-insecure-dangerous-php-functions

Comment: How is this not heavily downvoted? Isn't it bad practice to use `system`?

Comment: @YourCommonSense
It's platform dependent, can be insecure (I know you can escape the arguments, but it's still safer to use pure PHP to accomplish this), and hosting companies would have most likely disabled it.

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 OK fair. Let's call it a niche solution. Personally, I cannot imagine PHP running on any OS other than Linux and I forgot the time I was using a shared hosting.

Comment: @ThePixelDeveloper If your PHP script has access to delete files/folders in root directory, you have serious problems anyway.

Comment: I like this answer more than the others, it's only problem is the Linux dependency, and for the security problem, it's the caller job to check if it is really the intended directory or not, the function's only job is to *delete a directory* .

Comment: perfect one-liner! but because this is OS dependent, it's not universal, thus not preferable for me.

Comment: thank you do this work in shared host?

Comment: $dir is what you let it to be, for those with so many caveats about using this approach.

Answer (score 56):

Short function that does the job:

```
function deleteDir($path) {
    return is_file($path) ?
            @unlink($path) :
            array_map(__FUNCTION__, glob($path.'/*')) == @rmdir($path);
}
```

I use it in a Utils class like this:

```
class Utils {
    public static function deleteDir($path) {
        $class_func = array(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__);
        return is_file($path) ?
                @unlink($path) :
                array_map($class_func, glob($path.'/*')) == @rmdir($path);
    }
}
```

---

**With great power comes great responsibility**: When you call this function with an empty value, it will delete files starting in root (`/`). As a safeguard you can check if path is empty:

```
function deleteDir($path) {
    if (empty($path)) { 
        return false;
    }
    return is_file($path) ?
            @unlink($path) :
            array_map(__FUNCTION__, glob($path.'/*')) == @rmdir($path);
}
```

Comment: The static one doesn't work because $this === NULL when you call a static function on a class. It would work if `$this_func = array(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__);`

Comment: Can someone explain the line `array_map($class_func, glob($path.'/*')) == @rmdir($path)`? I guess he's recursing through the subfolders, but what does the == @rmdir part do? How does the <array of booleans> == <boolean> return the answer? Does it check if each return value of the recursion is the same as the boolean on the right?

Comment: It's a trick to merge two statements into one statement. This is because ternary operators allow only one statement per argument. `array_map(...)` removes all files within the directory, `@rmdir(...)` removes the directory itself.

Comment: Be careful! This function does not check if the path really exists. If you pass an empty argument, the function will start to delete files starting from the root! Add a sanity check to your path before you run this function.

Comment: Some people did not see Tatu's comment and recursively deleted `/`, so I appended a safeguarded version to my post.

Comment: Sorry but... I still not understanding the operation of the last line with array_map...

Comment: @PedroAntônio `array_map` calls a function (first argument) for each item returned by the glob and then continues to delete the dir itself in `@rmdir`.

Answer (score 40):

As seen in most voted comment on PHP manual page about `rmdir()` (see http://php.net/manual/es/function.rmdir.php), `glob()` function does not return hidden files.  `scandir()` is provided as an alternative that solves that issue.

Algorithm described there (which worked like a charm in my case) is:

```
<?php 
    function delTree($dir)
    { 
        $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..')); 

        foreach ($files as $file) { 
            (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? delTree("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file"); 
        }

        return rmdir($dir); 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: can you please explain is_dir("$dir/$file") - did not meet with the "$dir/$file"  parameter

Comment: What do you mean?  It checks if the entry found in a directory (`$file`) is a directory or a file.  `"$dir/$file"` is the same as `$dir . "/" . $file`.

Comment: I honestly did not know you can concatenate variables like this :)

thx

Comment: The only challenge I came across with this example is that it doesn't handle symlinks to directories vary well within the directory. To do this, change the is_dir check to `(is_dir("$dir/$file") && !is_link("$dir/$file"))`

Answer (score 24):

You may use Symfony's [Filesystem](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem/introduction.html) ([code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.php)):

```
// composer require symfony/filesystem

use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;

(new Filesystem)->remove($dir);
```

However I couldn't delete some complex directory structures with this method, so first you should try it to ensure it's working properly.

I could delete the said directory structure using a Windows specific implementation:

```
$dir = strtr($dir, '/', '\\');
// quotes are important, otherwise one could
// delete "foo" instead of "foo bar"
system('RMDIR /S /Q "'.$dir.'"');
```

And just for the sake of completeness, here is an old code of mine:

```
function xrmdir($dir) {
    $items = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item === '.' || $item === '..') {
            continue;
        }
        $path = $dir.'/'.$item;
        if (is_dir($path)) {
            xrmdir($path);
        } else {
            unlink($path);
        }
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .you save my time.

Comment: *"Don't reinvent the wheel"*. Thank you

Answer (score 19):

This is a shorter Version works great to me

```
function deleteDirectory($dirPath) {
    if (is_dir($dirPath)) {
        $objects = scandir($dirPath);
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            if ($object != "." && $object !="..") {
                if (filetype($dirPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $object) == "dir") {
                    deleteDirectory($dirPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $object);
                } else {
                    unlink($dirPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $object);
                }
            }
        }
    reset($objects);
    rmdir($dirPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can try as follows:

```
/*
 * Remove the directory and its content (all files and subdirectories).
 * @param string $dir the directory name
 */
function rmrf($dir) {
    foreach (glob($dir) as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) { 
            rmrf("$file/*");
            rmdir($file);
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplicity of the function is beautiful and it works excellently, except on dot files.

Answer (score 13):

I can't believe there are 30+ answers for this. Recursively deleting a folder in PHP could take minutes depending on the depth of the directory and the number of files in it! You can do this with one line of code ...

`shell_exec("rm -rf " . $dir);`

If you're concerned with deleting the entire filesystem, make sure your `$dir` path is exactly what you want first. NEVER allow a user to input something that can directly delete files without first heavily validating the input. That's essential coding practice.

Comment: I am doing clean up on the /tmp folder so ```shell_exec("rm -rf " . sys_get_temp_dir() . "/{$dir}");``` is easy, straight forward and lighting fast.

Comment: This! but I would do `shell_exec("rm -rf '$dir'");`

Comment: I'm using this with a cron job to remove uploaded security camera images from the previous day. Obviously as stated above don't let users have access to this and make sure you got your $dir correct!

Comment: Not everyone has access to `shell_exec()`, but if you do then this would be the way to go.

Answer (score 12):

This one works for me:

```
function removeDirectory($path) {
    $files = glob($path . '/*');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        is_dir($file) ? removeDirectory($file) : unlink($file);
    }
    rmdir($path);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here you have one nice and simple recursion for deleting all files in source directory including that directory:

```
function delete_dir($src) { 
    $dir = opendir($src);
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                delete_dir($src . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                unlink($src . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
    rmdir($src);

}
```

Function is based on recursion made for copying directory. You can find that function here:
[Copy entire contents of a directory to another using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050859/copy-entire-contents-of-a-directory-to-another-using-php)

Answer (score 7):

The Best Solution for me

```
my_folder_delete("../path/folder");
```

code:

```
function my_folder_delete($path) {
    if (in_array($path, ['.', '/'])) return; // ensure to avoid accidents
    if(!empty($path) && is_dir($path) ){
        $dir  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS); //upper dirs are not included,otherwise DISASTER HAPPENS :)
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
        foreach ($files as $f) {if (is_file($f)) {unlink($f);} else {$empty_dirs[] = $f;} } if (!empty($empty_dirs)) {foreach ($empty_dirs as $eachDir) {rmdir($eachDir);}} rmdir($path);
    }
}
```

p.s. REMEMBER! 
dont pass EMPTY VALUES  to any Directory deleting functions!!!  (backup them always, otherwise one day you might get DISASTER!!)

Answer (score 5):

Litle bit modify of alcuadrado's code - `glob` don't see files with name from points like `.htaccess` so I use scandir and script deletes itself - check `__FILE__`.

```
function deleteDir($dirPath) {
    if (!is_dir($dirPath)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("$dirPath must be a directory");
    }
    if (substr($dirPath, strlen($dirPath) - 1, 1) != '/') {
        $dirPath .= '/';
    }
    $files = scandir($dirPath); 
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file === '.' || $file === '..') continue;
        if (is_dir($dirPath.$file)) {
            deleteDir($dirPath.$file);
        } else {
            if ($dirPath.$file !== __FILE__) {
                unlink($dirPath.$file);
            }
        }
    }
    rmdir($dirPath);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Glob function doesn't return the hidden files, therefore scandir can be more useful, when trying to delete recursively a tree.

```
<?php
public static function delTree($dir) {
   $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..'));
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? delTree("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file");
    }
    return rmdir($dir);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Example for the Linux server: `exec('rm -f -r ' . $cache_folder . '/*');`

Comment: I usually like to add a sanity check on $cache_folder before running rm -rf to avoid costly mistakes

Answer (score 4):

I want to expand on the answer by @alcuadrado with the comment by @Vijit for handling symlinks. Firstly, use getRealPath(). But then, if you have any symlinks that are folders it will fail as it will try and call rmdir on a link - so you need an extra check.

```
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach($files as $file) {
    if ($file->isLink()) {
        unlink($file->getPathname());
    } else if ($file->isDir()){
        rmdir($file->getPathname());
    } else {
        unlink($file->getPathname());
    }
}
rmdir($dir);
```

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment on the answer directly.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this because it still returns TRUE when it succeeds and FALSE when it fails, and it also prevents a bug where an empty path might try and delete everything from '/*' !!:

```
function deleteDir($path)
{
    return !empty($path) && is_file($path) ?
        @unlink($path) :
        (array_reduce(glob($path.'/*'), function ($r, $i) { return $r && deleteDir($i); }, TRUE)) && @rmdir($path);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
function recursiveDelete($dirPath, $deleteParent = true){
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirPath, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $path) {
        $path->isFile() ? unlink($path->getPathname()) : rmdir($path->getPathname());
    }
    if($deleteParent) rmdir($dirPath);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using DirectoryIterator an equivalent of a previous answer…

```
function deleteFolder($rootPath)
{   
    foreach(new DirectoryIterator($rootPath) as $fileToDelete)
    {
        if($fileToDelete->isDot()) continue;
        if ($fileToDelete->isFile())
            unlink($fileToDelete->getPathName());
        if ($fileToDelete->isDir())
            deleteFolder($fileToDelete->getPathName());
    }

    rmdir($rootPath);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this simple 12 line of code for delete folder or folder files...
happy coding... ;) :)

```
function deleteAll($str) {
    if (is_file($str)) {
        return unlink($str);
    }
    elseif (is_dir($str)) {
        $scan = glob(rtrim($str,'/').'/*');
        foreach($scan as $index=>$path) {
            $this->deleteAll($path);
        }            
        return @rmdir($str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
function delete_folder($folder) {
    $glob = glob($folder);
    foreach ($glob as $g) {
        if (!is_dir($g)) {
            unlink($g);
        } else {
            delete_folder("$g/*");
            rmdir($g);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete all files in Folder
`array_map('unlink', glob("$directory/*.*"));`
Delete all .*-Files in Folder (without: "." and "..")
`array_map('unlink', array_diff(glob("$directory/.*),array("$directory/.","$directory/..")))`
Now delete the Folder itself
`rmdir($directory)`

Answer (score 1):

2 cents to add to [THIS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3349792/1702853) above, which is great BTW

After your glob (or similar) function has scanned/read the directory, add a conditional to check the response is not empty, or an `invalid argument supplied for foreach()` warning will be thrown. So...

```
if( ! empty( $files ) )
{
    foreach( $files as $file )
    {
        // do your stuff here...
    }
}
```

My full function (as an object method):

```
    private function recursiveRemoveDirectory( $directory )
    {
        if( ! is_dir( $directory ) )
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException( "$directory must be a directory" );
        }

        if( substr( $directory, strlen( $directory ) - 1, 1 ) != '/' )
        {
            $directory .= '/';
        }

        $files = glob( $directory . "*" );

        if( ! empty( $files ) )
        {
            foreach( $files as $file )
            {
                if( is_dir( $file ) )
                {
                    $this->recursiveRemoveDirectory( $file );
                }
                else
                {
                    unlink( $file );
                }
            }               
        }
        rmdir( $directory );

    } // END recursiveRemoveDirectory()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that works perfect:

```
function unlink_r($from) {
    if (!file_exists($from)) {return false;}
    $dir = opendir($from);
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if ($file == '.' OR $file == '..') {continue;}

        if (is_dir($from . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)) {
            unlink_r($from . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
        }
        else {
            unlink($from . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
        }
    }
    rmdir($from);
    closedir($dir);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
function Delete_Directory($Dir) 
{
  if(is_dir($Dir))
  {
      $files = glob( $Dir . '*', GLOB_MARK ); //GLOB_MARK adds a slash to directories returned

      foreach( $files as $file )
      {
          Delete_Directory( $file );      
      }
      if(file_exists($Dir))
      {
          rmdir($Dir);
      }
  } 
  elseif(is_file($Dir)) 
  {
     unlink( $Dir );  
  }
}
```

Refrence:
https://paulund.co.uk/php-delete-directory-and-files-in-directory

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the YII helpers

$directory (string) - to be deleted recursively.

$options (array) - for the directory removal. 
Valid options are:
traverseSymlinks: boolean, whether symlinks to the directories should be traversed too. Defaults to `false`, meaning that the content of the symlinked directory would not be deleted. Only symlink would be removed in that default case.

```
public static function removeDirectory($directory,$options=array())
{
    if(!isset($options['traverseSymlinks']))
        $options['traverseSymlinks']=false;
    $items=glob($directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'{,.}*',GLOB_MARK | GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        if(basename($item)=='.' || basename($item)=='..')
            continue;
        if(substr($item,-1)==DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)
        {
            if(!$options['traverseSymlinks'] && is_link(rtrim($item,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)))
                unlink(rtrim($item,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
            else
                self::removeDirectory($item,$options);
        }
        else
            unlink($item);
    }
    if(is_dir($directory=rtrim($directory,'\\/')))
    {
        if(is_link($directory))
            unlink($directory);
        else
            rmdir($directory);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  function rrmdir($dir) {
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $objects = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
      if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
        if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") 
           rrmdir($dir."/".$object); 
        else unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
      }
    }
    reset($objects);
    rmdir($dir);
  }
 }
?>
```

Have your tryed out the obove code from php.net

Work for me fine

Answer (score 0):

For windows:

```
system("rmdir ".escapeshellarg($path) . " /s /q");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Playnox's solution, but with the elegant built-in DirectoryIterator:

```
function delete_directory($dirPath){
 if(is_dir($dirPath)){
  $objects=new DirectoryIterator($dirPath);
   foreach ($objects as $object){
    if(!$object->isDot()){
     if($object->isDir()){
      delete_directory($object->getPathname());
     }else{
      unlink($object->getPathname());
     }
    }
   }
   rmdir($dirPath);
  }else{
   throw new Exception(__FUNCTION__.'(dirPath): dirPath is not a directory!');
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not remember from where I copied this function, but it looks like it is not listed and it is working for me

```
function rm_rf($path) {
    if (@is_dir($path) && is_writable($path)) {
        $dp = opendir($path);
        while ($ent = readdir($dp)) {
            if ($ent == '.' || $ent == '..') {
                continue;
            }
            $file = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $ent;
            if (@is_dir($file)) {
                rm_rf($file);
            } elseif (is_writable($file)) {
                unlink($file);
            } else {
                echo $file . "is not writable and cannot be removed. Please fix the permission or select a new path.\n";
            }
        }
        closedir($dp);
        return rmdir($path);
    } else {
        return @unlink($path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Easy...

```
$dir ='pathtodir';
if (is_dir($dir)) {
  foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $filename) {
    if ($filename->isDir()) continue;
    unlink($filename);
  }
  rmdir($dir);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure, Given path is directory or file then you can use this function to delete path

```
function deletePath($path) {
        if(is_file($path)){
            unlink($path);
        } elseif(is_dir($path)){
            $path = (substr($path, -1) !== DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) ? $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : $path;
            $files = glob($path . '*');
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                deleteDirPath($file);
            }
            rmdir($path);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nicely formatted helper function that can be used with a framework like Laravel

```
if(!function_exists("remove_directory")){
    
   /**
    * remove_directory
    * 
    * Removes all contained files and folders in the directory, then removes
    * itself
    * 
    * 
    * @param {string} $directory
    * 
    */
    function remove_directory(string $directory){

    

        if (!is_dir($directory)) {

            throw new InvalidArgumentException("{$directory} must be a directory");

        }

        if (substr($directory, strlen($directory) - 1, 1) != '/') {

            $directory .= '/';

        }


        $files = glob($directory . '*', GLOB_MARK);


        foreach ($files as $file) {

            if (is_dir($file)) {

                remove_directory($file);

            } else {

                unlink($file);

            }

        }


        rmdir($directory);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using laravel, then you can simply use the `File` facade:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

File::deleteDirectory($pathToDirectory);
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple solution

```
$dirname = $_POST['d'];
    $folder_handler = dir($dirname);
    while ($file = $folder_handler->read()) {
        if ($file == "." || $file == "..")
            continue;
        unlink($dirname.'/'.$file);

    }
   $folder_handler->close();
   rmdir($dirname);
```

Comment: in dirname can`t be other dirs, only files, but isn`t problem make a little change in my code ;)

Comment: Using `$_POST` without any validation ⇒ security breach.

Answer (score -4):

Platform independent code.

Took the [answer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#115598) from PHP.net

```
if(PHP_OS === 'Windows')
{
 exec("rd /s /q {$path}");
}
else
{
 exec("rm -rf {$path}");
}
```