# Deleting non-empty directory with PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I recursively delete a directory and its entire contents (files+sub dirs) in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123/how-do-i-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-entire-contents-filessub-dirs)

I need to delete a directory in PHP. There's no built-in way to remove directories with files in them, so I know I'll have to use someone else's script.

I've found, and I think I'll use:

```
<?php

// simply pass the directory to be deleted to this function

function rrmdir($dir)
{
    if (is_dir($dir)) // ensures that we actually have a directory
    {
        $objects = scandir($dir); // gets all files and folders inside
        foreach ($objects as $object)
        {
            if ($object != '.' && $object != '..')
            {
                if (filetype($dir . '/' . $object) == 'dir')
                {
                    // if we find a directory, do a recursive call
                    rrmdir($dir . '/' . $object);
                }
                else
                {
                    // if we find a file, simply delete it
                    unlink($dir . '/' . $object);
                }
            }
        }
        // the original directory is now empty, so delete it
        rmdir($dir);
    }
}
?>
```

I can't see anything wrong with it, I'm just a bit nervous about not only deleting files, but entire directories, and recursively at that.

Is there any reason this wouldn't work? Have you used anything different?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349753/php-delete-directory-with-files-in-it

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. It doesn't have the check to see if the file is '..' or '.' though. I'm guessing it does something different and doesn't need to, but I want people's verification that I'm not going to be deleting my website

Comment: Can I please get some sort of yeah or nay for the scripts?

Comment: @user828584, my answer to that question linked by Lucanos skips dot files outside of the loop. I'd take that over the code in your question any day.

Comment: Thanks. If you post that as the answer, I'll accept it. People seem to go for that kind of thing