# But it still deletes how to delete a directory using PHP

Tags: php, directory

I have a PHP script for deleting a directory. This deletes the target directory but shows an error message if there are more than one file but it still deletes the directory..weird..;Shown error given below:-

```
Warning: rmdir(uploads/dd4a96d6907035a1d011b9394d779d3c) [function.rmdir]: Directory not empty in /home/.../public_html/deletepost.php on line 21
```

here's php

```
<?php

$dir = $row['album_path'];

17     foreach(scandir($dir) as $file) {
18     if ('.' === $file || '..' === $file) continue;
19     if (is_dir("$dir/$file")) rmdir_recursive("$dir/$file");
20     else unlink("$dir/$file");
21     rmdir($dir);
22     }

?>
```

Am I doing anything wrong with the code?

Comment: `rmdir();` requires that the directory be empty. You must delete all files within the directory before you can proceed with removing said directory.

Comment: @ Jordan Hugh McKimm Hi thanks for the answer..I found a solution in this page and it works fine.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267086/php-unlink-all-files-withing-a-directory-and-then-deleting-that-directory

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to delete folder without warning in PHP

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/793-php-warning-rmdir-directory-not-empty