# delete json-file with php

Tags: php, json

I'm writing a json-file inside a generated folder. After an hour I want to delete the folder with its content automatically.
I tried:

```
$dir = "../tmpDir";
    $cdir = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value)
   {
      if (!in_array($value,array(".","..")))
      {
         if (is_dir($dir.'/'.$value))
         {
             if(filectime($dir.'/'.$value)< (time()-3600))
             {  // after 1 hour
                $files = glob($dir.'/'.$value); // get all file names
                foreach($files as $file)
                { // iterate files
                    if(is_file($file))
                    {
                        unlink($file); // delete file
                    }
                }
                rmdir($dir.'/'.$value);


                /*destroy the session if the folder is deleted*/

                if(isset($_SESSION["dirname"]) && $_SESSION["dirname"] == $value)
                {
                    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
                    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
                }
             }
         }
      }
   }
```

I get: rmdir(../tmpDir/1488268867): Directory not empty in **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/....** on line **46**

if I remove the

```
if(is_file($file))
{

}
```

I get a permission error

Maybe someone knows why I get this error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349753/delete-directory-with-files-in-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easier to use your native O/S to delete the directory when it comes to things like these, so you don't have to write a horrible loop that *may have some edge cases that you could miss* and then end up deleting things you shouldn't have!

```
$path = 'your/path/here';

if (PHP_OS !== 'WINDOWS')
{
    exec(sprintf('rm -rf %s', $path));
}
else
{
    exec(sprintf('rd /s /q %s', $path));
}
```

Of course, tailor the above to your needs. You can also use the [backtick operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) if you want to avoid the overhead of a function call (negligible in this case, anyway). It's also probably a good idea to use [escape_shell_arg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) for your `$path` variable.

For a one-liner:

```
exec(sprintf((PHP_OS === 'WINDOWS') ? 'rd /s /q %s' : 'rm -rf %s', escape_shell_arg($path)));
```

Regardless, sometimes it's easier to let the O/S of choice perform file operations.

Answer (score 3):

`rmdir()` removes directory if u want remove file then you should use `unlink()` function

Proper aporach would be using `DirectoryIterator` or `glob()` and looping through files then deleting them and after you do it you can remove empty directory.

You can also call system command `rm -rf direcory_name` with `exec()` or `shell_exec()`

useful links:

- [Delete directory with files in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349753/delete-directory-with-files-in-it)
- [How to delete a folder with contents using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334398/how-to-delete-a-folder-with-contents-using-php)
- [PHP: Unlink All Files Within A Directory, and then Deleting That Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267086/php-unlink-all-files-within-a-directory-and-then-deleting-that-directory)

I've found pretty useful function on php.net that removes hidden files as well

```
 public function delTree($dir) { 
    $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); 

    foreach ($files as $file) { 
      (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? delTree("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file"); 
    } 

    return rmdir($dir); 
  }
```

Comment: I want to delete the folder with its content

Comment: Thank you this is really helpfull, but somehow the is_file() doesn't fire on my .json files - so I guess my only option is to use system commands

Comment: check if this file has proper chmods