# Deleting folder and files inside directory in php

Tags: php

I am trying to find a way of deleting a folder which is located inside another (eg accounts/username - i want to delete username but it has 2 folders inside (1 names images and other named videos) - with files inside.

I have tried

```
$accounts = "accounts";
$uploaddir = "$username";
$image_dir = 'image';
$video_dir = 'video';

$image_folder = "$accounts$username$image_dir/";
$uploadfile = $image_folder . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

$dir = "$accounts/$uploaddir";
array_map('unlink', glob($dir."/*"));
rmdir($dir);
```

Comment: would that delete the files and folders

Comment: Check that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349753/delete-directory-with-files-in-it

Comment: is this an already exiting upload folder or are u deleting the folder in the fly when uplaod ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123/how-do-i-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-entire-contents-files-sub-dir/3352564#3352564

Answer (score 1):

key function : **unlink** files ,**scandir** and **rmdir** but you need to scan that directory for all its content and do accordingly

1.Unlink on case of file 
2.Remove on case of Directory using is_dir() function.

```
<?php
  function deleteDir($dir) {
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $objects = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
      if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
        if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") 
           deleteDir($dir."/".$object); 
        else unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
      }
    }
    reset($objects);
    rmdir($dir);
  }
 }
?>
```

onyour case:

```
$dir = "$accounts/$uploaddir";
deleteDir($dir);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use following function,

```
unlink(file_path);
```

You can remove complete folder/files. refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Here is function, I use all time:

```
function delete_directory($dirname) {
   if (is_dir($dirname))
      $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);

   if (!$dir_handle)
      return false;
   while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
         if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
            unlink($dirname."/".$file);
         else
            delete_directory($dirname.'/'.$file);    
      }
   }
   closedir($dir_handle);
   rmdir($dirname);
   return true;
}
```