# Cannot delete a folder and entire content

Tags: php, unlink, rmdir

I create in my project a directory with subdirectories and files.
After I do my duty with files content I want to delete the entire folder(all the subdirectories, files and main directory).

I use ZF2 framework and this is my function:

```
    public function recursiveRemoveDirectory($directory) {
        foreach(glob("{$directory}/*") as $file) {
            if(is_dir($file)) {
                $this->recursiveRemoveDirectory($file);
            } else {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }

        rmdir($directory);
    }
```

and I call this function in this way:

```
$this->recursiveRemoveDirectory($dirPath);
```

My function erase all contents(subdirectories and files) of the directory but not the directory.

I see that already exist questions on this topic, but I didn't find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think there [Delete directory with files in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349753/delete-directory-with-files-in-it) you can find all ways to delete folder using php.

In addition I recommend you this library for file operations: https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem

It's incapsulate all thing that you need and well documented here: http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/api/

Comment: I saw that topic, but I didnt find the solution. For me doesn't work

Comment: Please check chmod for folder that you want to delete.

Comment: That folder has full control