# Delete or Unlink folders inside a directory using PHP

Tags: php

I am able to delete files inside my upload folder inside my server using PHP `unlink()` see below code, but script only deletes files, how to include and delete folders?

```
$files = glob('upload/*'); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
  if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file); // delete file
}
```

I found this code but it gives me a permission denied error.

```
array_map('unlink', glob("upload/*"));
```

And used this code below

```
function deleteFiles($directory) {
    $recursive = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($recursive, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir()) {
            rmdir($file->getRealPath());
        } else {
            unlink($file->getRealPath());
        }
    }
    rmdir($directory);
}

deleteFiles('upload');
```

But permission denied error displays

> Warning: rmdir(upload): Permission denied in

I am trying this code my self on my localhost and my user account is administrator.

Comment: Check [`rmdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php).

Comment: Did you read this: http://php.net/manual/bg/function.unlink.php Also there is an example of recursivly deleting all files and dirs. Your permission denied is maybe because of trying to delete `..` directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete directory with files in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349753/delete-directory-with-files-in-it)

Comment: @Don't Panic I am using the top answer code but got this error instead `'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(upload\*,upload\*): Permission denied' `

Comment: Well, even after using code that _should_ delete a folder rather than a file, it's still certainly possible that the user account you're executing this with doesn't have the necessary permission to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after modifying the function `deleteFiles()` i need to set my directory to 0777 using below code

`chmod($directory,0777);`

Then after deleting i need to remake the directory again using `mkdir`  below is the modified code.

```
function deleteFiles($directory) {
    chmod($directory,0777);
    $recursive = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($recursive, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir()) {
            rmdir($file->getRealPath());
        } else {
            unlink($file->getRealPath());
        }
    }
    rmdir($directory);
}

deleteFiles('upload');

mkdir("upload", 0700);
```

Comment: if your query was solved please accept your  answer and upvote the ones that were useful, this's how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rmdir`.  [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) This will allow you to delete empty directories in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that would remove files (unlink) and directories (rmdir) recursively.

There is a library that lets you work with the file system easily. It is a Symfony component called `Filesystem`. You can use it as an independent component easily. It has `remove` method that can do what you need: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html#remove

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function which use [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

> The RecursiveDirectoryIterator provides an interface for iterating recursively over filesystem directories.

```
function deleteFiles($directory) {
    $recursive = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($recursive, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir()) {
            rmdir($file->getRealPath());
        } else {
            unlink($file->getRealPath());
        }
    }
    rmdir($directory);
}
```

Call it like

```
 deleteFiles('uploads');
```

Comment: when you downvote, try to comment in doing so you are helping me to improve my answer and not to repeat my mistakes.