# Script to delete the contents of a file php

Tags: php, shell

I would like to do a script in order to delete the contents of a file in php.

I have this :

```
<?php

class DelShell extends AppShell {


    public function main() { 
        $target = WWW_ROOT . DS . "pdf" ;

        $dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($target);

        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

        foreach($iterator as $fichier){
            $fichier->isDir() ? rmdir($fichier) : unlink($fichier);
        }

        unlink($target);



    }

}
```

It's work but I have some problems : I have "Warning" with the rmdir .

Comment: "Warning" saying what?

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking for `.` and `..`? You can't remove those directories.

Comment: FYI `$fichier->isDot()` will return `true` for `.` and `..`. Alternatively you can pass flag `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS` in the constructor to exclude from the start

Comment: What , I dont understand ?

Comment: Your code  `$fichier->isDir() ? rmdir($fichier) : unlink($fichier);` is attempting to remove `.` and `..`

Comment: So wat i need to do ?

Comment: I can't test cause I have a problme with my Mac

Comment: Check if the $ichier is a `.` or `..` before you run `$fichier->isDir() ? rmdir($fichier) : unlink($fichier);`. Given you two methods on how to do that already.

Comment: $fichier->isDot() ? rmdir($fichier) : unlink($fichier); like that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete directory with files in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349753/delete-directory-with-files-in-it)