# Is there any way to delete the main Folder and it's sub folder in CodeIgniter4?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to delete a main folder along with all the files and subfolders inside it. I have tried a code block that uses `glob()` to iterate over all files and then calls `rmdir()` to delete the main folder and `unlink()` to delete the files. However, the subfolders are not getting deleted. How can I modify this code to also delete the subfolders?

Example code:

```php
foreach (glob($dir . '/*') as $file) {
    if (is_dir($file)) {
        rmdir($file);
    } else {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
rmdir($dir);
```

Comment: Use a [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) and a [RecursiveIteratorIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) to traverse the entire subtree and remove everything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete directory with files in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349753/delete-directory-with-files-in-it)

Answer (score -2):

Certainly! Here's a modified version of your code that uses `delete_files()` from CodeIgniter's File Helper to delete the main folder, its files, and subfolders:

```php
// Load the File Helper
helper('file');

// Specify the directory path
$dir = 'path/to/main/folder';

// Delete all files and subfolders recursively
foreach (glob($dir . '/*') as $file) {
    if (is_dir($file)) {
        delete_files($file, true);
    } else {
        unlink($file);
    }
}

// Delete the main folder
rmdir($dir);
```

In this code, the `delete_files()` function is called for each subfolder encountered in the `foreach` loop. It deletes all the files and subfolders within each subfolder recursively.

If a file is encountered instead of a subfolder, it is deleted using `unlink()` as before.

Finally, after deleting all the files and subfolders, `rmdir()` is used to remove the main folder.

Remember to adjust the `$dir` variable with the actual path to the main folder you want to delete.