# PHP mkdir() Function - If Folder Exists

Tags: php, forms

I have a PHP Script that creates a folder based on a form. I'm wondering if there is a way to NOt create and replace that folder if it already exists?

```
<?php 
mkdir("QuickLinks/$_POST[contractno]");
?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? What does your program do?

Comment: The program creates a folder based on input from a form, and then copies a template folder into the new folder. I'm wondering if there is also a way to tell the script that if the folder is already there; don't copy anything? It a in-house project, password is needed to access the web-page.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php):

```
<?php 
$path = "QuickLinks/$_POST[contractno]";
if(!is_dir($path)){
  mkdir($path);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

In general:

```
$dirname = "whatever";
if (!is_dir($dirname)) {
    mkdir($dirname);
}
```

In particular: **be very careful** when doing filesystem (or any other type of sensitive) operations that involve user input! The current example (create a directory) doesn't leave much of an open attack surface, but validating the input can never hurt.

Answer (score 4):

Use [is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) to check if folder exists

```
$dir = "/my/path/to/dir";
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    if (false === @mkdir($dir, 0777, true)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Unable to create the %s directory', $dir));
    }
}
```

Attention to the uncontrolled input, it is very dangerous!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
<?php 
    if (!is_dir("QuickLinks/$_POST[contractno]"))
        mkdir("QuickLinks/$_POST[contractno]");
?>
```

Comment: This seems to have worked. Is there a way to do this for copying a folder? If the folder already exists then don't copy anything?

Comment: Yeah, this should work: `<?php if (!is_dir($dest_dir)) shell_exec("cp -r $src_dir $dest_dir"); ?>`. If there is problem with shell_exec() function, replace it with some other copying function inspired from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050859/copy-entire-contents-of-a-directory-to-another-using-php) topic.

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Answer (score 1):

Use the is_dir-function of PHP to check if there is already a directory and call the mkdir-function only if there isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

Do some validation rules (regexp) here before using POST variable to create the directory !

```
if(!file_exists("QuickLinks/$_POST[contractno]"))
    mkdir("QuickLinks/$_POST[contractno]");
```

Comment: file_exists doesn't differentiate between files and directories, so a file with the name you are looking for will produce a false true. is_dir checks if it exists AND if it is a directory

Comment: @hellsgate: Which is the better approach in such cases. You can't create the directory if a file or named socket under that same name exists. So `is_dir` sounds like the more exact approach, but can lead to false negatives and additional errors. Purely fictional. But the fallback code should be invoked for existing files *and* directories.

Comment: @mario: Good point. For this scenario, I now realise file_exists is the better option because of the reasons you list.