# PHP copy all images folder from one folder to another

Tags: php, linux

I am working on some code that will take all the images in one folder and copy them into another folder and then delete the original folder and it content.

I have:

```
copy('images/old-folder/*', 'images/new-folder/');
unlink('images/old-folder/');
```

but this does not work :( but it doesn't work I mean the files dont copy over and the old-folder is not deleted :(

I even tried:

```
system('cp images/old-folder/* images/new-folder/');
```

and that didn't work either :( Please help.

I have even tried to change the permissions of the two folders:

```
chmod('images/old-folder/', 0777);
chmod('images/new-folder/', 0777);
```

Comment: Have you tried a fully qualified path? Does the account have permissions?

Comment: `copy()` is not supposed to be working on directories but single files only, as said in the documentation. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7775949/180709) for a pure PHP solution. If you can, please don't use shell calls that have to be used with extreme caution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach(glob('images/old-folder/*') as $image) {
    copy($image, 'images/new-folder/' . basename($image)); unlink($image);
}
rmdir('images/old-folder');
```

check the docs: [glob](http://php.net/glob), [rmdir](http://php.net/rmdir), also you might find user comments on rmdir useful.

EDIT:

added [basepath](http://php.net/basepath) to the second parameter to the copy function which has to be an actual path and not a directory.

Comment: this kinda works, it removes the images and the folder but does not copy the images into the new-folder

Comment: im going to try to change the permissions of the image before copying it in the foreach

Comment: see my reply, I made some changes to the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$src = 'pictures';
$dst = 'dest';
$files = glob("pictures/*.*");
      foreach($files as $file){
      $file_to_go = str_replace($src,$dst,$file);
      copy($file, $file_to_go);
      }

?>
```

Found here: [PHP copy all files in a directory to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148427/php-copy-all-files-in-a-directory-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version from @Prasanth that should work (not tested)

```
<?php
    $oldfolder = 'images/new-folder';
    $newfolder = 'images/old-folder';

    $files = glob($oldfolder . '/*');

    foreach($files as $file){
        $filename = basename($file);
        copy($file,  $oldfolder . '/' . $filename);
        unlink($file);
    }
    rmdir($oldfolder);
?>
```