# How to copy folder to another folder

Tags: php

I want to copy a folder containing files to another destination using php. I found a code snippet, but I'm not getting how it works.

Is it possible to copy folder to another folder?

```
copyfolder('folder', 'folder_copy');
function copyfolder($source, $destination) 
{ 
       $directory = opendir($source); 
       mkdir($destination);
       while(($file = readdir($directory)) != false) 
       { 
         copy($source.'/' .$file, $destination.'/'.$file); 
       } 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy entire contents of a directory to another using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050859/copy-entire-contents-of-a-directory-to-another-using-php)

Comment: you can copy the files from one folder to another folder with the above code. copyfolder('source folder', 'destination folder'). Hope u understand the code

Comment: Look at this answer: Copy entire contents of a directory to another using php

I think this is what you are looking for, enjoy.

Comment: ok working perfectly ,thanks every one

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the system function:

```
system("/bin/cp $source $destination");
```

Comment: if i use system("/bin/cp $source $destination"); will it work on server ?

Comment: AFAIK everyone has those permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try [PHP Copy](http://php.net/manual/de/function.copy.php)

This should also work with folders.

`bool copy ( string $source , string $dest [, resource $context ] )`

```
<?php
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "copy $file schlug fehl...\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: You say _should_. Is that a guess? The PHP compiler source code says _argument to copy() function cannot be a directory_.