# Copy directory and files with php code

Tags: php, file, directory, copy

I need help or answer is it possible to copy directory with all content.
I have two web sites on same server.
And i need to copy:

source: home/public/first/images

destination: home/public/second/images

and if is possible to do that i need to setup crone job for auto sync that two directories every 5 minutes for example.
I was try this
[screenshot code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfUAv.png)
Sorry for bad English i hope you understand my problem

Comment: What's wrong with your previous try?

Comment: I goth this msg but actualy nothing hapents 
Copy Paste completed!

Comment: this is code i use $source = '/path/to/source/';
$destination = 'path/to/destination/';

$sourceFiles = glob($source . '*');

foreach($sourceFiles as $file) {

    $baseFile = basename($file);

    if (file_exists($destination . $baseFile)) {

        $originalHash = md5_file($file);
        $destinationHash = md5_file($destination . $baseFile);
        if ($originalHash === $destinationHash) {
            continue;
        }

    }
    copy($file, $destination . $baseFile);
}
echo "<H3>Copy Paste completed!</H3>"; //output when done

Comment: what message? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050859/copy-entire-contents-of-a-directory-to-another-using-php) there's another example. Read careful. **Please put your code in the original answer (edit-it), not in the comments**