# Copying folder to other folder with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to move folder to other folder, with all it's files. Both folders are in root directory. Tried a lot of ways, and always get no result.
Here is my latest atempt:

```
$source = "template/"
$dest = "projects/"
function copyr($source, $dest){
    if (is_link($source)) {
        return symlink(readlink($source), $dest);
    }

    if (is_file($source)) {
        return copy($source, $dest);
    }
    if (!is_dir($dest)) {
        mkdir($dest);
    }
    $dir = dir($source);
    while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
        // Skip pointers
        if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
            continue;
        }
        copyr("$source/$entry", "$dest/$entry");
    }
    $dir->close();
    return true;
}
```

Need professional glance to tell me, where I'm getting it wrong?

**EDIT:**

Sorry for wrong tags. 
Problem is - nothing is happening. Nothing is being copied. No error messages. Simply nothing happens.
File structure:

[image]

Comment: Please don't tag a question with every version of PHP. The PHP tag is sufficient unless you're having an issue with a specific version, and in that case just use the one version tag.

Comment: dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050859/copy-entire-contents-of-a-directory-to-another-using-php

Comment: Do you have permissions to create destination folder? Do you get any errors? What is wrong? For example, only directories are created but they are empty and no files created. Or may be even root destination folder is not created?

Comment: did you try absolute path instead of relative paths for `source` and `dest`? Also do you have permission on destination folder?

Comment: this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12763962/1848929

Comment: Still - not working. Edited problem.  Problem is - nothing is happening. Nothing is being copied. No error messages. Simply nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to try and do the following

1. How do you run the scrips? Do you open page in browser or run script in command line? If you open page in browser this might be an issue with permissions, paths (relative and not absolute) and errors not shown but logged.
2. Use absolute folder paths instead of relative paths. For example `/var/www/project/template`.

Apply [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function to all paths and check (output) the result. If path is wrong (folder does not exist, separators are wrong etc) you will get empty result from the function.

Make sure to use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of `/` if you run your script on Windows. I can not check if `/` works on Windows now but potentially this might be an issue. For example

```
copyr($source.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$entry", $dest.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$entry);
```

2. Check warnings and errors. If you do not have permission you should get warning like this

> PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied

You may need to enable warnings and errors if they are disabled. Try for example to make an obvious mistake with name and check if you get any error message.

3. Try to use tested solution from one of the answers. For example [`xcopy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050859/copy-entire-contents-of-a-directory-to-another-using-php/12763962#12763962) function.
4. Try to add debug messages or run your script in debugger step by step. Check what is happening, what is executed etc. You can add debug output near any operator like (just an idea):

   echo 'Creating directory '.$name.' ... ';
   mkdir($name);
   echo (is_dir($name) ? 'created' : 'failed').PHP_EOL;

Comment: I'm using xampp, these files are in my htdocs, so I believe all have all rights needed.

Comment: Try very simple things first. For example try to create a folder and check for error messages. Make things as simple as possible and you will find what is wrong. I guess this might be issue with paths and permissions.

Comment: Do you run xampp on Windows or Unix?

Comment: No errors. Seems paths are invalid. Xampp is on windows

Comment: Just FYI, if you use windows you need different folder separator :) I'm using Linux so I forget about this many times.

Comment: what separator should be used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110170/discussion-between-victor-smirnov-and-justinast).