# how to fix file name too long in rename function php

Tags: php

I have a quizzes webpage, where when you copy a quiz it adds *-Copied* after its namne, but when the *-Copied* phrases increased here was the problem, I use `rename()` function in php to move the quiz to the desired path. So with this long file name it results in this error
`File name too long in /home1/...`

I have tried using `copy()` instead of `rename()` but `copy()` copies only files not whole directories so it didn't work resulting in this error `The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory`

how can I fix this?

Comment: `-Copied` is 6 characters long, so check if the existing file/folder name + 6 is going to go over the name length limitation of the host operating system, and if so, truncate the necessary number of characters from the existing file/folder name before appending `-Copied` and attempting the rename operation.

Comment: You're probably looking at an operating system limit rather than a php limit.

Comment: P.S. Is there any chance you ought to be managing all this data in a database rather than (what sounds like) duplicating folders full of HTML/PHP/whatever files across your website?

Comment: You could try one of these solutions, [Copy entire contents of a directory to another using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2050859/1427878) - but it is not even a given, that you won't have the same issue with too long paths in that context as well. _"but when the -Copied phrases increased here was the problem"_ - you mean, after you created a copy of a copy of a copy ... of a quiz, so that the path eventually contained `-Copied-Copied-Copied-Copied`...? Maybe you should not do _that_ then, but rename the first copy, _before_ you create another copy from it?

Comment: "how to fix file name too long in rename function php?" use shorter names ^^

Comment: For a start, extract a [mcve]. Also, check the documentation, the comments there and existing bugs.